# How to choose ECDH and ECDHE with curve more than 192 in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I am using tomcat server, where I came across a situation where the [TestSSLServer](http://www.bolet.org/TestSSLServer/) tool reports the below.

Highly appreciate your expertise in recommending a solution to the finding where I can choose ECDH curve size greater than 192. In the server the suites are just ECDH or ECDHE. I wonder how to restrict the curve value for the EC above 192.

How can i resolve this at the server end.

```
Minimum EC size (no extension):   256
Minimum EC size (with extension): 160
Supported curves (size and name) ('*' = selected by server):
    162  sect163k1 (K-163)
    162  sect163r1
    162  sect163r2 (B-163)
    192  sect193r1
    192  sect193r2
    231  sect233k1 (K-233)
    232  sect233r1 (B-233)
    237  sect239k1
    281  sect283k1 (K-283)
    282  sect283r1 (B-283)
    407  sect409k1 (K-409)
    408  sect409r1 (B-409)
    569  sect571k1 (K-571)
    570  sect571r1 (B-571)
    160  secp160k1
    160  secp160r1
    160  secp160r2
    192  secp192k1
    192  secp192r1 (P-192)
    224  secp224k1
    224  secp224r1 (P-224)
    256  secp256k1
  * 256  secp256r1 (P-256)
    384  secp384r1 (P-384)
    521  secp521r1 (P-521)
=========================================
**WARN[SK004]: Server supports ECDH parameters smaller than 192 bits**
```

Answer (score 0):

I *believe* what you need to do is get rid of the first three curves in the list.  By default, Tomcat is probably using all of the curves provided by the Sun EC provider.  So...  I think you can set those by setting them in your certificate file, from Tomcat docs for SSLCertificateFile, "In addition to the certificate, the file can also contain as optional elements DH parameters and/or an EC curve name for ephemeral keys, as generated by openssl dhparam and [openssl ecparam](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Command_Line_Elliptic_Curve_Operations#Generating_EC_Keys_and_Parameters), respectively. The output of the respective OpenSSL command can simply be concatenated to the certificate file."  So, pick the curves you want to use (none of the 163 ones) and then generate parameters for them and add them to the end of your certificate.